# Are all Wii WiiWare and Virtual Console games available on Wii U eShop?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, virtual-console, wiiware

Does the Wii U eShop contain all the WiiWare and Virtual Console games from Wii Shop Channel?

Are there any such Wii games known to be specifically not compatible with the Wii U (e.g. with regard to System Transfer)?

Comment: I don't know if the Wii U shop currently contains all of the Wii shop's content, but I know that the *A Link to the Past* Virtual Console title only got released on the Wii U shop in late 2013.

Comment: I'm really not sure if we need a tag for [tag:eshop]...

Comment: @Nolonar - do you mean a native Wii U version of A Link to the Past (made to work with its tablet controller), or support for the Wii Shop Channel Virtual Console backward compatibility via built-in Wii emulation?

Comment: @acalypso I meant the native Wii U version. I can effortlessly play the game on Wii mode, and I'm kind of disappointed, that Nintendo doesn't let me download the Wii U version, even though I posess the Wii one. I asked support, but they said I have to stick with Wii mode.

Comment: I have answered to this added issue in the updated version of my answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

Nintendo currently only sells a small fraction of the Virtual Console titles on the Wii U as they are converted to Wii U for controller compatibility and other reasons.

You can still purchase these games on the Wii U from within the Wii virtual machine environment via the Shop Channel and Nintendo is still distributing games for the Wii through this shop (including some of it's Club Nintendo giveaways).

It is very unlikely that many if not most of these games will ever be ported for native Wii U play due to the radical change in controller schemes. All Wii U games are required to support the tablet as the primary controller.

As for the second part of your question, the only significant game I am aware of that will not transfer to the Wii U's Wii emulator is *Lost Winds*. I have also found anecdotal evidence that DLC for *Final Fantasy The After Years* fails to transfer as well and neither can be downloaded from the Wii Shop Channel on Wii U.

One added note as this was touched on in comments. Nintendo has indicated they will re-issue an unspecified number of Virtual Console games on Wii U and if you have already purchased the Wii version **and** it is linked to the Nintendo account you transferred from a Wii to the Wii U, then the new release will be offered to you at a greatly discounted prices ranging between $0.50 to $1.50 in the U.S. (*if you did not transfer your Wii profile to your Wii U then you are not eligible for the discount*).

*Correction: In April 2014, Lost Winds became transferable from the Wii to the Wii U. To transfer it you will need to have held onto your old Wii system and repeat the transfer process. Otherwise you'll need to repurchase it.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, I understood the Wii games from Shop Channel are not natively supported by Wii U, but since Wii U has full Wii compatibility built in via emulation, including Shop Channel, I am be able to buy, download and play all Wii games from Shop Channel (including its Virtual Console department) - with Lost Winds being the only known exception. This, of course, is valid as long as Wii Shop Channel is online. Did I got it right?

Comment: Yep. Spot on. You got it.

Comment: FWIW, I did a little bit of clean up to make things clearer in the post. If this answers your question, please accept it when you have a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be extra clear here, can you confirm that the contradicting information on this post is incorrect? https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130506222025AAO5sVR

That is to say, any games which "are no longer available on the Wii U's Wii Mode's Shop Channel" would also be delisted from the original Wii's Shop Channel as well, correct? Before I do my Wii Transfer, I want to ensure there are no "Wii-exclusive" games I'm missing out on when I move to Wii U.

Comment: Also, can you please clarify what you mean that the Wii Shop now includes "some of it's Club Nintendo giveaways"? As far as I know there were only two -- Doc Louis' Punchout and Grill Off with Ultra Hand... are those really available for sale on the Wii U Shop Channel?

Comment: @Jon I read that Yahoo page and have never heard about any of that. Nor have I heard about any games being pulled from the Wii shop. Nor have I heard about any Club exclusives now being for sale separately. As far as I am aware, at this time any Wii game you purchased from the Wii e-Shop will transfer to the Wii emulator on the Wii U, including DLC. The original question had to do with games being re-issued so you could buy them from the Wii U e-shop as a native Wii U game (separate from the e-shop within the Wii emulator). That information is still accurate as stated above.

Comment: @Jon edit on delisted titles. I did actually find some information here that is pertinent ( http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/2000407-wii-virtual-console-and-wiiware/67022403 ). It appears that all Commodore 64 games, the Donkey Kong Country series and TMNT games were delisted (along with some other random games based on publisher licensing) for **new purchase**. But if you already bought them you can re-download them.

Comment: Oh, and clarifying on the Club Nintendo giveaways. Club Nintendo was still (in 2014) providing download codes for games that needed claimed and downloaded from within the Wii Shop menu and not the Wii U e-shop. Such as the grill off title, etc...

Comment: @BryanC. right, so in this case, mentioned titles are no longer available on regular Wii Shop Channel either. So in other words, there should currently be 1-to-1 parity between Wii and Wii U Shop Channels, and in general this should always be the case.

Comment: @Jon, yes if you mean what I think you're trying to say which is there is 1-to-1 parity between the Wii Shop on a Wii and the Wii Shop on a Wii U. The Wii U e-shop is a different beast. :)